# Ansible "until:" and register variables

Tags: ansible

I got this task

```
---
- win_updates:
  ignore_errors: yes
    category_names: '*'
    reboot: yes
    state: installed
  register: win_updates
  until: win_updates.installed_update_count == 0
```

It updates Windows servers and reboots until there are no updates left.

At the end of the playbook I want to print out all installed updates:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ win_updates.updates }}'
```

This worked when i installed the updates without "until:". Now it's empty. From the Ansible documentation it says the structure is different, when you register a variable with a loop:

> When you use register with a loop, the data structure placed in the
> variable will contain a results attribute that is a list of all
> responses from the module. This differs from the data structure
> returned when using register without a loop

So i tried to print out "{{ win_updates.results }}" which is nonexistent:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'results'"}
```

When i debug win_updates i can indeed find no .results there:

```
"msg": {
    "attempts": 2,
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "failed_update_count": 0,
    "filtered_updates": {},
    "found_update_count": 0,
    "installed_update_count": 0,
    "reboot_required": false,
    "updates": {}
}
```

For me it seems like my loop overwrites the variable instead of adding each run to .results. Is there a difference between until: and loop: that i'm not aware of?

Comment: until have to work with retries?  At the moment, giving "retries:" without an "until:" condition has no effect.

Comment: retries is set in the ansible.cfg. And it works, there are updates, i start the playbook, it says "FAILED - RETRYING: [123.123.123.123]: host1 (3 retries left)." and finishes with ok and all updates are gone. My problem is not that the playbook won't work, but that i can't output the variable that was registered

Comment: ok, it seems that with until, register doesnt register results of old executions https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58918

Comment: mhm ok, so i  guess the best approach would be to remove "until:", copy the task a few times and register win_updates1, win_updates2 etc. That looks not that clean as i hoped it would, but it should work i guess. What would happen if i write it in a block and run "until:" within the block and not the task?

Comment: i have a solution to use a custom filter which save the different step in a json file if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom filter named customfilter1 here,:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import json

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'customfilter1': self.customfilter1
        }

    def customfilter1(self, obj, file):
        if obj["attempts"] == 1:            
            result = [obj]
            json_file = json.dumps(result, sort_keys = False, indent= 4)
            with open(file, 'w') as f:
                f.write(json_file)
        else:         
            with open(file) as f:
                result = json.load(f)
            result.append(obj)
            json_file = json.dumps(result, sort_keys = False, indent= 4)
            with open(file, 'w') as f:
                f.write(json_file)           

        return False
```

the plugin returns always the value false...

and you use it:

```
- win_updates:
  ignore_errors: yes
    category_names: '*'
    reboot: yes
    state: installed
  register: win_updates
  until: win_updates | customfilter1(file) or win_updates.installed_update_count == 0
  vars:
    file: /yourfolder/file.json
```

the file json contains all history, so you could modify the plugin to just keep what you want...

```
[
{
    "attempts": 1,
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "failed_update_count": 0,
    "filtered_updates": {},
    "found_update_count": 0,
    "installed_update_count": 2,
    "reboot_required": false,
    "updates": {something...}
},
{
    "attempts": 2,
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "failed_update_count": 0,
    "filtered_updates": {},
    "found_update_count": 0,
    "installed_update_count": 1,
    "reboot_required": false,
    "updates": {something...}
}, and so on

]
```

after that you could do a task to trap all names of package..(the file is json format, list of dictionaries)

so i have no window so i dont know your ouput..

a sample with random number:

```
- name: simulate
  command: shuf -i 0-5 -n 1
  register: out 
  until: out | customfilter1(file) or out.stdout | int == 2
  retries: 100
  vars:
    file: /yourfolder/file.json

- name: group results
  set_fact:
    result: "{{ result | d([]) + [item.stdout] }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('file',file) | from_json }}"
  vars:
    file: /yourfolder/file.json

- name: group results
  debug:
    var: result
```

display result (stop when random number is 2) you have the list of all random numbers:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": [
        "5",
        "3",
        "3",
        "1",
        "3",
        "0",
        "4",
        "0",
        "5",
        "2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh, what a hell of a workaround :D Thanks for your effort! I'm a bit sad that it's not easier to manage this, but i will try it out. And since it seems to be a limitation with Ansible i'll mark this as answer. I would prefer the classic way of registering though, but again thank you this helps :)

Comment: Since the registration of loops might be not implemented i would choose to use your workaround. Sadly I'm getting just a list of all Updates, they are not mapped to the individual hosts. The updates differ on every host so i would need the hostnames aswell within /yourfolder/file.json. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @EdFred, difficult to answer to your new question, because its long time..and your first question was complex. To avoid confusion, I suggest you to close this question by validating the answer and open a new question with the plugin you have tried and explain your new problem..

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for that, that hopefully will find it's way to Ansible: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58918#issuecomment-1057451791